# Using PostSharp with TraceAttribute for logging with HttpContext's SessionID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, logging, aop, postsharp

I'm using PostSharp with the `TraceAttribute` on each class in order to write to log files. A new requirement is to be able to prepend each log entry with the `SessionID`.

PostSharp doesn't seem to be able to work this way though. I've tried the two approaches that made sense to me and neither work.

**Try #1**

I added a string parameter to the `TraceAttribute` constructor to be passed in and used by the `OnEntry`, `OnExit` and `OnException` methods.

```
private readonly string _sessionID;

public TraceAttribute(string sessionID)
{
    _sessionID = sessionID;
    logger = new Logger();
}

public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    logger.LogMethodExit(string.Format("Session {0} Exiting {1}.{2}", _sessionID, args.Method.DeclaringType.FullName, args.Method.Name));
}
```

My controllers were decorated with the [Trace] attribute originally and I modified to this approach...

```
[Trace(HttpContext.Session.SessionID)]
```

This doesn't work as the `HttpContext` is not available in a static context.

So that idea is out the window.

**Try #2**

So my next try was to simply create the `sessionId` variable locally to each method in the `TraceAttribute`...

```
public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    var sessionID = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
    logger.LogMethodEntry(string.Format("Session {0} Entering {1}.{2}", sessionID, args.Method.DeclaringType.FullName, args.Method.Name));
}
```

This doesn't work either as again, the `HttpContext` is not yet available and is a `null` object at runtime as soon I run the solution..

**Try #3**

```
public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    string sessionID = "Not initialized";
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID != null)
        sessionID = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
    logger.LogMethodEntry(string.Format("Session {0} Entering {1}.{2}", sessionID, args.Method.DeclaringType.FullName, args.Method.Name));
}
```

Is there any way to get the session information into a `TraceAttribute` that is weaved with PostSharp in this manner? Some workaround that can accomplish this goal?

Comment: Your second try should work..., are you sure you can access HttpContext.Current from inside the method you're tracing (not the aspect)? Maybe you method is running in a new thread, that would explain why HttpContext.Current isn't available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, I was missing my session being turned in in web.config.

Added this line to config and it works fine now.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```